# Xamarin forms : On IOS how to set as pop async the button of the tab bar ?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am working in the xamarin forms, i did a tabbed page  with navigation .
The problem is when navigate trow page and tabbed my icon (button of the tab bar) instead of coming back in the previse page it go to the first that attache to the icon . How can i make in sort it will to a pop async ?

Thanks.

Comment: Tabbed pages don't work like this. If you want behaviour of page stack (push/pop), you have to use single pages (content page or whatever) instead of tabbed pages. And push and pop manually

Comment: Not very clear on your question, could you provide the illustration or your code?